# How to calculate the Mean Median Mode and Range for datas from Input Python

Tags: python, range, mean, median, mode

I am trying to Calculate the mean, median, mode and range for sets of data in Python, and to  Interpret these statistics in the context of data and how to describe and interpret data displays using median, mean and range.

My Code so far is:

```
from statistics import median
from statistics import mean
from statistics import mode
from math import isnan
from itertools import filterfalse
title = input('Definition of data set: ')
data = (float(input("Enter a list element separated by space: "))
        xy = mean(data)
        print(x)
        y = statistics.mode(data)
        print(y)
        z = statistics.median(data)
        print(z)
```

But the code doesn't work...
and i believe its completely wrong.

Could anyone help by 24th of October???????

Answer (score 0):

The way you are defining '*data*' is wrong. You can try the code below. I only change the '*data*' variable.

```
from statistics import median
from statistics import mean
from statistics import mode
from math import isnan
from itertools import filterfalse
title = input('Definition of data set: ')
# Input list of element wit space and convert it to list
data = list(map(float, input('Enter the list of element: ').split()))
print(data)
x = mean(data)
print(x)
y = mode(data)
print(y)
z = median(data)
print(z)
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried the code and it works well, but when type in more than 6 numbers there is an error:                    Definition of data set: heights
Enter the list of element: 2.34 1.89 1.34 1.56 1.27 1.78 1.90
[2.34, 1.89, 1.34, 1.56, 1.27, 1.78, 1.9]
Mean:  1.7257142857142858
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 11, in <module>
    y = mode(data)
  File "/opt/python-3.6/lib/python3.6/statistics.py", line 507, in mode
    'no unique mode; found %d equally common values' % len(table)
statistics.StatisticsError: no unique mode; found 7 equally common values

Comment: For me it work alright for typing more than 6 numbers. I think your problem is with statistics library. It gives error because there is no repeating number in the list you wrote. When I wrote the same list [2.34 1.89 1.34 1.56 1.27 1.78 1.90], It doesn't give error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want input as a list of floating point numbers separated by space. You need to convert that into a list of floats which you can then pass to each of the statistical functions:

```
from statistics import mean, median, mode

data = input('Input values separated by space: ')

list_of_values = list(map(float, data.split()))

for func in mean, median, mode:
    print(f'{func.__name__}={func(list_of_values)}')
print(f'range={min(list_of_values)}-{max(list_of_values)}')
```

**Example:**

```
Input values separated by space: 3 2 2.5 3 9 7.1
mean=4.433333333333334
median=3.0
mode=3.0
range=2.0-9.0
```

Comment: Thank you Sooo Much!!!!!!!! You really helped me with this problem :)

Comment: I also have another question, How do you figure out the range of the data... would it be range(data)    ????                                                                                       Thanks!!!!!!!!!!1

Comment: @Jocelyn Do you mean you want the lowest and highest values in the list? If so, see edit